# Jquery table formatting

Tags: jquery, combobox, telerik

I am binding the data to a Telerik MVC MultiColumn Combo box. I am trying to align three columns (e.selectedField.fieldName, e.concatField1, e.concatField2) in three td to make a table. How to apply style to the below textValue and bind this value as a table?

```
// Bind the data to the list control.
$.each(e.data, function (idx, record) {

    var textValue = record[e.selectedField.fieldName] + " " + record[e.concatField1]+" " + record[e.concatField2];

    bindData.push({ Value: record[e.valueField], Text: textValue });

});

ctrl.dataBind(bindData);
```

Comment: Some text seems to have dropped in "trying to align three columns ... in three to make a. What are you trying to make?

Comment: might be user gave td and table in html tags, which did not show up here...